# Is it possible to receive an FM signal without a tank circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, rf, radio, frequency-modulation, tank

I was broadcasting FM signals at MHz frequencies in my room. I know that an AM radio will not work to receive FM transmissions.

The special issue is that an AM radio can get any AM signal without a tank circuit by only setting an amplifier.

I am struggling when I have to turn the trimmer capacitor to receive the right FM station signals inside a tank circuit. Is there a way to get and receive an FM station signal without a tank circuit like in AM radios?

Below is a picture of the FM receiver. Can this circuit be made without a tank circuit?

[image: circuit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean receiving all FM stations at once.

No. The LC circuit is a must for slope detection of FM transmission signals.

"The slope detector circuit is also called frequency discrimination circuit. This circuit operates by detecting the variations in the input signal's slope to obtain the original modulating signal. It uses tuned LC circuit at the front, followed by diode rectification and low pass filtering. It is **similar to AM envelope detector circuit except the tuned circuit.**"

From:

https://www.ee-diary.com/2023/04/how-to-design-fm-slope-detector.html